# I need help identifying this capacitor and finding a replacement

Tags: capacitor, identification

I'm guessing at 107 6.3 V

but... that really looks like 1Q7

this circuit board is originally from Poland.

I released the magic smoke on this one but luckily took a really bad picture of it first.

[image: Cap]

Comment: A better photograph is needed please.

Comment: The "Q" looks like an image processing artifact on a "0", which would make it a 100 µF 6.3 V tantalum or perhaps tantalum polymer capacitor.  100 µF/6.3 V is a very common combination.  "Q" is an rarely-used tolerance code for -10%/+30% but I've never seen it written as part of the capacitance.

Comment: That’s awesome.  Any idea what the little squigley is after the 6.3?

Comment: Could be a manufacturer's mark but it doesn't match any of the "big" manufacturers (Kyocera, Kemet, Panasonic, AVX, et. al.) that I can see.

Comment: Can you tell what the application of this device was and provide a circuit diagram if possible, it would be much easier

Comment: I can send more pics but no diagrams. It is a controller for a stop motion camera slider